# Get Site Collection Administrators using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, site, collection

How can I get the Site Collection Administrators using PowerShell in SharePoint 2013? I have tried the below script but it just returns me to the prompt with no results:

```
$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
  $spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication
    foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {
      foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
      {
        Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"
      }
    $site.Dispose()
  }
$rootSite.Dispose()

Enter Site URL: http://myurl.local
```

*EDIT: The reason I was not getting any results was because I didn't have **SharePoint_Shell_Access** on the SP database. I would have expected PowerShell to throw an error when adding the SP snap-in but it didn't.*

Comment: Any specific scope? One site? Multiple sites? All sites in different web applications?

Comment: Ideally I would target a Web App and get a list of all Site Collections and Site Collection Administrators. However I'd just be happy to get the Site Collection Administrators for a targeted Site Collection.

Comment: added some examples as an answer.

Comment: You shold not dispose ``$site``. You are disposing objects, that were created by different process and not by you with ``new`` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was not getting any results was because I didn't have **SharePoint_Shell_Access** on the SP database. I would have expected PowerShell to throw an error when running "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue    
    $siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"
    $rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
    $spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication
    foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
    {
        foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
        {
            Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"
        }
        $site.Dispose()
    }
    $rootSite.Dispose()
```

Comment: I found this one too but it did not work for me. It does not list any results.

Comment: Did you run powershell as administrator?

Comment: I **always** run PS as administrator :)

Comment: It turns out I did not have SP Shell Access. I thought I did. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

While this piece of Powershell will work and return all site collections in a webapplication:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue

$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"

$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{
    foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
    {
        Write-Host "$($siteAdmin.ParentWeb.Url) - $($siteAdmin.DisplayName)"
    }
    $site.Dispose()
}
$rootSite.Dispose()
```

This will work as well.

For a specific SharePoint Site collection:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue

$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"

Get-SPSite -Identity $siteUrl | select-object url, Owner, SecondaryContact
```

Or all Site collections in a webapplication:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ea SilentlyContinue

$webApp = Read-Host "Enter Webapplication URL"

Get-SPWebApplication -Identity $webApp | Get-SPSite -limit all | select-object url, Owner, SecondaryContact
```

Comment: The last two scripts appear to be a step closer because they list the site URL's but under the "Owner" and "SecondaryContact" headers there are no results, Does it work for you?

Comment: @Rubio My bad, had an error from my tests. Yes i do get my primary and secondary site collection administrators. Owner is the primary SCA and SecondaryContact is the second SCA. Which script did you try?

Comment: I tried the second and third scripts

Comment: Still no results?

Comment: Do you enter a sitecollection URL? Like https://something/sites/sitecollection ?

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

```
   foreach($spSite in $siteCollections)


  $siteURL =  $spSite.Url;

  $siteCollectionAdmins = $spSite.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators;
}
    foreach ($admin in $siteCollectionAdmins)
    {

      Write-Host $spSite.Url "|" $admin.DisplayName;
      Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -value " $($siteURL) | $($admin.DisplayName)";

    }

  $spSite.Dispose();

}}
```

full script I have published [get-site-collection-administrators](http://www.get-spnote.com/2018/04/get-site-collection-administrators.html) this script will generate a CSV file on specified output path

Comment: Thank you Ganesh Sanap for format correctingthe Code Section